# How do I name a substituent which is a cycloalkane which is attached by a chain of more than one carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: Diagram picture]

Above is a picture of an alkane. How would I name this using IUPAC rules? I understand how to name other substituents such as (1,1-dimethylethyl) and some other methyl groups, but I don't know how to name the cycloalkane substituents. What are the rules for naming cycloalkanes as substituents?

Comment: Without touching the actual case, things like cycloalkanes as substituents are cycloalkyls.

Comment: Note that "1,1-dimethylethyl" is not a preferred IUPAC name.

Comment: @Loong I thought that 1,1-dimethylethyl was the IUPAC name and that t-butyl was the common name. Where would the parent chain start for this molecule?